# Analog CCTV over wireless

Tags: wireless, cctv

I work in a security company, and we have a client who would like CCTV put in around their premises. They have an existing analog system (over COAX) that we were going to replace, but he would also like some extra cameras on a separate building and it is not feasible to dig a trench the whole way.

We were trying to find the best way to do this but have had no luck. is there any way to convert analog video signal to a wireless signal that is then picked up on the other side, or if that is not possible is there a way to convert the coax to a CAT5e cable that we can then use a wireless network to connect with?

Thanks

Comment: Matt, this is the wrong site. It is about information security, not video wiring. I'm not sure where to send you. Hopefully someone else will know what site to point you to.

Comment: Try amateur radio at Stack Exchange. It's a little closer to what you need.

Answer (score 0):

Using wireless for security devices is a very bad idea as it can get jammed. No matter how good the crypto is, an attacker doesn't have to actually break it but simply flood garbage data over the frequencies with a stronger transmit power than the legitimate device and your CCTV goes dark.

I highly suggest you rethink your approach and switch to wired cameras (if possible network cameras - coax and analog are a thing of the past).